# Ranking last row of dataframe by entire column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to rank the values in the last row of a dataframe by the corresponding column above and return a list of the ranks by the 'min' amount. Example below:

```
df = [[10, 2, 8, 4], [12, 6, 4, 1], [8, 4, 3, 2], [9, 3, 4, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)

    0  1  2  3
0  10  2  8  4
1  12  6  4  1
2   8  4  3  2
3   9  3  4  6
```

The desired result would rank 9 in column 0 against the entire column, so it would return a 3 for that element in the list. In column 2, "4" is ranked 2nd in that column (hence the 'min' method of ranking). Desired result below:

```
result = [3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

```
rs = df.rank(method="dense", ascending=False).iloc[-1].tolist()
print(rs)
```

**Output**

```
[3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Do you think there's a more efficient way to do this in terms of time using lists as opposed to a dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by using list?